# Inherit a business object for a DTO?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, webforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update only 1 field of a big Business Object inside a transaction (Best approach) ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519029/update-only-1-field-of-a-big-business-object-inside-a-transaction-best-approach)

Hello fellows, I want to update only two propertes of a big business object/class.

Business Object(20 fields), UpdateObject(4 fields)

Can I make a small child object inheriting those 4 fields from the business object and pass it to DB layer for update? Please show me a little example. Thanks